# cant open any apps on my ipad

Tags: ipad, drm, ios

I got a iPad (1) and no mbp or windows for itunes so I hooked it up to another persons mac to get the latest updates for it.

It was all good for a while till the battery died the other day. After I charged it I was not able to open any apps except the ones that came pre installed.

not being able to play plants vs zombies any more makes me :(

how to fix please

Comment: When you try and run an application, does it come up with an error message?

Comment: it will open the app for 1/10th of a second and then close, no error nothing.

Comment: Just because I'm curious. Are you saying you don't have a computer of your own? Why can't you run iTunes and use your own computer to sync your iPad?

Comment: I don't have a computer with windows or a mac Pc. Just 3 running ubuntu :) iTunes in wine is crap, with no USB support.

Comment: Yeah, I thought Linux was the likely answer. How about Windows or OSX in VirtualBox?

Comment: I've tried osx 10.7 in virtual box on a x86 but that failed. should try on my x64 some time. not interested in windows much, would rather buy a macbook air if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the permissions for your ipad and the installed apps.

Not sure if you've tried this.  But try installing any free application, the ipad will ask for your iTunes store password.  Once it has finished downloading, try and start another app.

Comment: I was thinking that. i have logged out and back in the itunes thing. did not make a diff, will try download an app tonight when I'm home.